# Swift. How to choose a random user from Firebase Database?

Tags: database, swift, random, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Database, every users data is being stored, now in my app I want to be able to choose a random user from the database how can I do that?

This is my JSON tree from my database:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "bge8yeAx8FedX8ozXRGl5ltWkbD3" : {
      "Coins" : 0,
      "Dollars" : 0,
      "GamesLost" : 0,
      "GamesWon" : 0
    },
    "lzsPuNwHbIZI1J8k40FspYRV4XQ2" : {
      "Coins" : 52,
      "Dollars" : 46,
      "GamesLost" : 0,
      "GamesWon" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Go check out my recent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038712/how-do-i-retrieve-a-random-object-from-firebase-using-a-sequential-id/53330758#53330758). I think it is exactly what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a call to users, take the ids given back to you, and pick one at random with a basic random number. If after making a call to users you have 10 user ids in an array you would want to get a random number between 0-9 and then make a call to firebase with the userId. I don't believe Firebase has any built in code for this.